# Jsoup Check if a tag exists

Tags: java, css, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm using jsoup to extract some ads from a page and i need to check if a class exists but i'm not doing it right:(
Here is the html:
[image]

I need to check if the class .large-4.medium-5.large-text-right.medium-text-right.columns exists and if so, i need to extract the element inside  it but i've got stuck at checking if that class exists:(

Here is my code:

```
    Elements pageSearchPrice = page2
                                .select("li[itemtype=https://schema.org/Offer] > div[class=listing-data]");
    for(int j=0; j < pageSearchTitle.size(); j++) {
       if(pageSearchPrice.get(j).hasClass(".large-4.medium-5.large-text-right.medium-text-right.columns")) {
          String price = pageSearchPrice.get(j).select("strong[itemprop=price]").text();
          list.get(index1).setPrice(price);
          index1++;
    }else {
          list.get(index1).setPrice("No price");
           index1++;
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of alternatives: Have you tried putting whitespaces between classes? And two, instead of selecting that div, maybe you can actually select the second div (not ideal but it can be a dirty fix until the solution has been figured out)

Comment: I've tried that and it's not working:( i was thinking that maybe i'm doing the checking in a wrong way

Comment: Have you debugged the program to see if you actually are getting the correct `pageSearchPrice` object?

Comment: Yes, i mean pageSearchPrice returns the right number of elements but i need to check for every element if it has that div

Comment: Can you try making multiple `hasClass` calls? Such as `pageSearchPrice.get(j).hasClass("large-4") && pageSearchPrice.get(j).hasClass("medium-5")` and so on? I would also suggest that looking for classes with dots, i.e. `.large-4` is not going to be valid

Comment: I've tried that and it's not working:(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181904/discussion-between-mayhem-and-truica-sorin).

Comment: Side note: In your code you iterate over ```pageSearchTitle```, but in the loop body you read out ```pageSearchPrice```. Seems strange to me, why you would not loop over ```pageSearchPrice``` directly with a foreach loop

Comment: What is not working about your code? Do you get an error, or is ```pageSearchPrice``` not containing the ```div``` you are loking for after all? Did you check with a debugger? If you get a StackTrace, please include it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be better to choose an object and compare it with an empty string "", if it turns out to be true, then there is no object, if it is false, it exists, or vice versa, as it is more convenient

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).